# find incomplete statement error in perl

Tags: perl, find, runtime-error, aix

I am a newbie in perl. I was trying below command in perl script on AIX system..

```
my @filename= ("finame_name");
system("find $DIRPATH -name '@filename' -mtime +7 -xdev -exec rm -f {} \;");
```

I am getting  "find: incomplete statement" error. Even I tried to solve it by putting two and three backslashes(`\\`), but couldn't resolve it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This is why you should always use `use warnings`. Try printing your system command and see if it is what you think it is. I suspect you've forgotten that `$DIRPATH` is a Perl variable.

Comment: Does the `find` command work on cmdline at all?

Comment: Why are you using an array for your filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not appear to be a perl problem at all, but a problem with how you're calling `find`.  Add some debugging to your perl script, to see exactly what command is being executed, then run that command directly from the shell, and debug it that way:

```
my @filename= ("finame_name");
my $command = "find $DIRPATH -name '@filename' -mtime +7 -xdev -exec rm -f {} \;";
warn "Executing '$command'\n";
system($command);
```

Comment: Your answer helped me. I modified those commands...              system "find $DIRPATH -name '@filename'-mtime +7 | -xargs rm -f {} \;";

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with AIX's find, but there are some find variants, which require a path argument. Unlike GNU find, which searches the current directory when the path is missing, these find commands need an explicit path specified. Since you haven't shown `$DIRPATH`, it might be empty and therefore you might have

```
find -name ...
```

instead of

```
find /some/path -name ...
```